# How to define a Resharper rule to check boolean variable is prefixed with 'Is'?

Tags: c#, resharper

I want to define a resharper rule that will check if boolean variable starts with '**Is**' , eg `bool IsActive` , `bool IsSet`

Comment: Not sure you can do this but... this would be an awful idea in my opinion. Means you can't have names like `HasStarted`,  `Enabled` or `CenEdit`

Comment: yes, but its an requirement to have meaningful names for variables

Comment: Are you saying those 3 examples I gave are not meaningful?

Comment: A boolean is only ever true false. Saying "is" infront doesn't change this, and it doesn't generate any extra readability.
"HasError" might be a better name than "Error". Because, does "Error" == true mean that it has an error? or that no errors where there so you could safely proceed, yet "IsError" doesn't make sense.

Comment: they are, but its a requirement in particular project to have boolean variables start with Is. My question is : is there any way to check if  boolean variables are  prefixed with some keyword

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Naming_Style.html

reading this might give you a hint.

Comment: I would be tempted to (very gently) push back on that requirement, it's overly restrictive and I think counter productive. Anyway, I don't think Resharper (without a plugin at least) can help, you may need a Roslyn analyser.